# Can I change the list in the foreign key dependant on the Boolean in the models class?

Tags: python, django

```
class Batting(models.Model):
    home_team = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
```

Im using Django tables and was wondering is there a way to choose a different table in the foreign key with what the `home_team` variable is?  I want the home team selection of players to be different from that of an away team.

Comment: You can try using the [contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#module-django.contrib.contenttypes). Althoug I would suggest a simple one to one relation with two other models (which would have the actual foreign key) depending on the boolean field. (This is basically similar to what the content types framework would do under the hood anyway, just that the contenttypes framework won't be that efficient)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat no sure how to use that in this context. I know i could make this a lot easier but I just cant see it right now

Comment: Lets say you have two models `A` and `B`. Both of these models would have a one to one relationship with `Batting`. `A` would have some foreign key to some table, `B` to some other table. That's the best method I feel. Although as I said the contenttypes framework is also a solution but then it is not very efficient.

Comment: Yeah I'm considering a BattingHome and a BattingAway models to be honest. Was hoping to see if there was a more efficient way @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: @Joelad Can you explain more about what you're trying to model in your DB?

Comment: So I was hoping that the list of members that can be chosen would change depending on the boolean value. Its probably not very practical @schillingt

Comment: If that's the extent of the problemset, you can do that, but not in the model itself. You'll have to do the filtering ahead of time.

Comment: @schillingt That makes sense. I'm probably being too adventurous lol. I might just simplify it and make it 2 separate models.

Comment: My gut tells me that's a poor design as well. If you're early on in your data models it'd be worth taking a few steps back and looking at your data as a whole and figuring out where the relationships really lie.

Comment: @schillingt I made an opponents model. Think it makes more sense

Comment: "poor design" was a poor choice of words. I'm glad you found something that works.